# Checking overlap ranges between two prices

Tags: c#, asp.net, interval

I have a method (C#, .NET framework 4.0) to check overlapping ranges between two prices.

- I have a `process`, which will have one or more `price`(s).
- A `price` has one or more `range`(s), like height, length, width, etc.
- Each `range` has a min and max value.

How can I further optimize this code? Or is there a better way of doing this?

```
    public static bool CheckOverlapPriceRange(int formulaId, int rangeInfoId, ref List<int> overlapRangeInfoIds)
    {
        //TO CHECK IF RANGES(RANGE ITEMS) OF RANGE INFO IS/ARE OVERLAP WITH OTHER RANGE INFO RANGES UNDER SAME FORMULA.
        List<DAL.SurfaceTreatment.vw_ST_RangeItem_RangeInfo_Formula> rangeItemInfoFormulaToCompare = DAL.RangeInfoHandler.GetInvertLockedVwRangeItemRangeInfoFormula(formulaId, rangeInfoId);

        if (rangeItemInfoFormulaToCompare.Count > 0)
        {
            List<DAL.SurfaceTreatment.vw_ST_RangeItem_RangeInfo_Formula> rangeItemInfoFormulaToCheck = DAL.RangeInfoHandler.GetVwRangeItemRangeInfoFormula(formulaId, rangeInfoId);
            //bool overlap = true;
            //bool overlapInfoId = false;
            //BOOL OF ITEM IN EACH RANGE INFO.
            List<bool> overlapBools = new List<bool>();

            //LIST TO STORE PAIR OF RANGE INFO. ID AND BOOL TO DECIDE IF OVERLAP
            List<Tuple<int, bool>> rangeInfoIdBool = new List<Tuple<int, bool>>();

            //BOOL OF EACH RANGE INFO.
            //List<bool> overlapRangeInfoId = new List<bool>();

            //GET DISTINCT RANGE INFO. ID FROM FORMULAS TO COMPARE
            var infoIdsToCompare = rangeItemInfoFormulaToCompare
                    .Select(x => x.FK_rangeInfoId)
                    .Distinct()
                    .OrderBy(x => x);

            //*******************************************************************************
            //START - ONLY CHECK IF BOTH PRICES/RANGE INFOS HAVE THE SAME RANGES/MEASUREMENTS
            //*******************************************************************************
            List<DAL.SurfaceTreatment.vw_ST_RangeItem> rangeItemsToCheck = DAL.RangeItemHandler.GetVwRangeItems(rangeInfoId);

            foreach (int infoIdToCompare in infoIdsToCompare)
            {
                List<DAL.SurfaceTreatment.vw_ST_RangeItem> rangeItemsToCompare = DAL.RangeItemHandler.GetVwRangeItems(infoIdToCompare);

                //IF BOTH PRICES/RANGE INFOS HAVE SAME RANGE ITEMS/MEASUREMENT
                if (IsSameRangesMeasurement(rangeItemsToCheck, rangeItemsToCompare))
                {
                    foreach (DAL.SurfaceTreatment.vw_ST_RangeItem_RangeInfo_Formula tempToCheck in rangeItemInfoFormulaToCheck)
                    {
                        //FILTER FORMULAS TO COMPARE BY MEASUREMENT AND RANGE INFO. ID
                        List<DAL.SurfaceTreatment.vw_ST_RangeItem_RangeInfo_Formula> listFilterByMeasurementInfoId = rangeItemInfoFormulaToCompare
                            .Where(x => string.Compare(x.measurementName.Trim(), tempToCheck.measurementName.Trim(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
                            //.Where(x => x.FK_rangeInfoId == infoId)
                            .ToList();

                        foreach (DAL.SurfaceTreatment.vw_ST_RangeItem_RangeInfo_Formula tempToCompare in listFilterByMeasurementInfoId)
                        {
                            bool conditionA = false;
                            bool conditionB = false;

                            //IF BOTH ARE SAME MEASUREMENT
                            if (tempToCheck.measurementName.Trim().ToLower() == tempToCompare.measurementName.Trim().ToLower())
                            {
                                #region ASSUME ONE RANGES ARE BEFORE ANOTHER RANGES
                                //IF EITHER TO CHECK MIN OR TO COMPARE MAX IS INCLUSIVE
                                if (tempToCheck.rangeItemMinInclusive || tempToCompare.rangeItemMaxInclusive)
                                {
                                    //IF TO CHECK MIN EQUAL TO TO COMPARE MAX
                                    if (tempToCheck.rangeItemMin == tempToCompare.rangeItemMax)
                                    {
                                        //IF TO CHECK MIN AND TO COMPARE MAX ARE INCLUSIVE
                                        if (tempToCheck.rangeItemMinInclusive && tempToCompare.rangeItemMaxInclusive)
                                        {
                                            //THEY ARE OVERLAP
                                            //EXAMPLE
                                            //0 < X <= 1
                                            //         1 <= X < 2 
                                            overlapBools.Add(true);
                                            rangeInfoIdBool.Add(new Tuple<int, bool>(tempToCompare.FK_rangeInfoId, true));
                                            break;
                                            //return true;
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            conditionA = (tempToCheck.rangeItemMin >= tempToCompare.rangeItemMax);
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        conditionA = (tempToCheck.rangeItemMin >= tempToCompare.rangeItemMax);
                                    }
                                }
                                //IF NEITHER TO CHECK MIN OR TO COMPARE MAX IS INCLUSIVE
                                else if (!tempToCheck.rangeItemMinInclusive && !tempToCompare.rangeItemMaxInclusive)
                                {
                                    //IF MIN EQUAL TO MAX
                                    if (tempToCheck.rangeItemMin == tempToCompare.rangeItemMax)
                                    {
                                        //THEY ARE NOT OVERLAP
                                        //EXAMPLE
                                        //0 < X < 1
                                        //        1 < X < 2
                                        overlapBools.Add(false);
                                        rangeInfoIdBool.Add(new Tuple<int, bool>(tempToCompare.FK_rangeInfoId, false));
                                        break;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        conditionA = (tempToCheck.rangeItemMin > tempToCompare.rangeItemMax);
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    conditionA = (tempToCheck.rangeItemMin > tempToCompare.rangeItemMax);
                                }
                                #endregion

                                #region ASSUME ONE RANGES ARE AFTER ANOTHER RANGES
                                //IF EITHER TO CHECK MAX OR TO COMPARE MIN IS INCLUSIVE
                                if (tempToCheck.rangeItemMaxInclusive || tempToCompare.rangeItemMinInclusive)
                                {
                                    //IF TO CHECK MAX EQUAL TO TO COMPARE MIN
                                    if (tempToCheck.rangeItemMax == tempToCompare.rangeItemMin)
                                    {
                                        //IF BOTH TO CHECK MAX AND TO COMPARE MIN ARE INCLUSIVE
                                        if (tempToCheck.rangeItemMaxInclusive && tempToCompare.rangeItemMinInclusive)
                                        {
                                            //THEY ARE OVER LAP
                                            //EXAMPLE
                                            //0 < X <= 1
                                            //         1 <= X < 2
                                            overlapBools.Add(true);
                                            rangeInfoIdBool.Add(new Tuple<int, bool>(tempToCompare.FK_rangeInfoId, true));
                                            break;
                                            //return true;
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            conditionB = (tempToCheck.rangeItemMax <= tempToCompare.rangeItemMin);
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        conditionB = (tempToCheck.rangeItemMax <= tempToCompare.rangeItemMin);
                                    }
                                }
                                //IF NEITHER TO CHECK MAX OR TO COMPARE MIN ARE INCLUSIVE
                                else if (!tempToCheck.rangeItemMaxInclusive || !tempToCompare.rangeItemMinInclusive)
                                {
                                    //IF TO CHECK MAX EQUAL TO TO COMPARE MIN
                                    if (tempToCheck.rangeItemMax == tempToCompare.rangeItemMin)
                                    {
                                        //THEY ARE NOT OVERLAP
                                        //EXAMPLE
                                        //0 < X < 1
                                        //        1 < X < 2
                                        overlapBools.Add(false);
                                        rangeInfoIdBool.Add(new Tuple<int, bool>(tempToCompare.FK_rangeInfoId, false));
                                        break;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        conditionB = (tempToCheck.rangeItemMax < tempToCompare.rangeItemMin);
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    conditionB = (tempToCheck.rangeItemMax < tempToCompare.rangeItemMin);
                                }
                                #endregion

                                //IF EITHER CONDITION IS TRUE, THEY ARE NOT OVERLAP
                                if (conditionA || conditionB)
                                {
                                    overlapBools.Add(false);
                                    rangeInfoIdBool.Add(new Tuple<int, bool>(tempToCompare.FK_rangeInfoId, false));
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    overlapBools.Add(true);
                                    rangeInfoIdBool.Add(new Tuple<int, bool>(tempToCompare.FK_rangeInfoId, true));
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    //THIS infoIdToCompare IS NOT OVERLAP, HENCE SET TO FALSE
                    rangeInfoIdBool.Add(new Tuple<int, bool>(infoIdToCompare, false));
                }
            }

            if (rangeInfoIdBool.Count > 0)
            {
                rangeInfoIdBool = rangeInfoIdBool.OrderBy(x => x.Item1).OrderBy(x => x.Item2).ToList();

                bool isOverlap = true;
                foreach (int infoId in infoIdsToCompare)
                {
                    isOverlap = true;
                    var filterList = rangeInfoIdBool.Where(x => x.Item1 == infoId).ToList();
                    foreach (var tempFilter in filterList)
                    {
                        isOverlap = isOverlap && tempFilter.Item2;
                    }

                    //AS LONG AS THERE IS OVERLAP WITH ANY ONE OF THE RANGE INFO.
                    if (isOverlap)
                    {
                        overlapRangeInfoIds = filterList.Select(x => x.Item1).Distinct().ToList();

                        //foreach(var overlapRangeInfoId in overlapRangeInfoIds)
                        //{
                        //    if (CheckOverlapCategoryBetweenRangeInfos(rangeInfoId, overlapRangeInfoId))
                        //    {
                        //    }

                        //}

                        return isOverlap;
                    }
                }
                return isOverlap;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
            //if (overlapBools.Count > 0)
            //{
            //    foreach (bool tempBool in overlapBools)
            //    {
            //        overlap = (overlap && tempBool);
            //    }
            //    return overlap;
            //}
            //else
            //{
            //    return overlap;
            //}
        }
        else
        {
            //IF ONLY ONE PRICE/RANGE INFO, THERE IS NO OVERLAP TO CHECK
            //HENCE RETURN FALSE
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you explain what overlapping prices mean and how you check them? It's very hard to deduce it from you code ;-) so it's difficult to tell if it could be done better.

Comment: Lets say `price1` only have `height1`, `price2` also only have `height2`, `height1` is 1<= X <= 3, `height2` is 4 <= X <= 6, then they are not overlap. If `height2` is 3 <= X <= 5, then they are overlap. These rules only apply to prices with the same ranges, like both have height, length & width and they are overlap only if all three height, length & width are overlap. If `price1` have height, length & width but `price2` only have height & length, then they definitely not overlap.

Answer (score 5):

I am adding my comments at first glance. This is not a final review as this code needs lots of refactoring.

1. **Delete commented code**

   Never keep commented code; it adds distraction while reading by anyone else.
2. **Always check negative logic first to avoid nesting**

   Check conditional logic first to avoid nested statements as mentioned below rather returning at last. It will add readability in your code.

   ```
   if (rangeItemInfoFormulaToCompare.Count==0)
       return false;
   ```
3. **Unnecessary object creation**

   I did not find any usage to this `overlapBools`.
4. **Break your methods and condition check into smaller methods**

   To avoid clutter in your code, always check and calculate the complex statement into a method. You can later merge it back into the main method if it seems unnecessary.
5. **Proper naming convention**

   `temptocheck`, `ConditionA` and `ConditionB` will not help you much when you will require the read this code again. Please correct this.
6. **Merge code as needed**

   ```
   if (conditionA || conditionB)
   {
       rangeInfoIdBool.Add(new Tuple<int, bool>(tempToCompare.FK_rangeInfoId, false));
   }
   else
   {
       rangeInfoIdBool.Add(new Tuple<int, bool>(tempToCompare.FK_rangeInfoId, true));
   }

   //This code can be rewritten as this, 
   rangeInfoIdBool.Add(new Tuple<int, bool>(tempToCompare.FK_rangeInfoId, 
   !(conditionA || conditionB)));
   ```
7. **Try to encapsulate your condition logic into a class which handles your complex logic in one place.**

   ```
   public class RangeComparer
   {
       private readonly Range _source;
       private readonly Range _target;


       public RangeComparer(Range source, Range target)
       {
           _source = source;
           _target = target;
       }

       public bool Compare()
       {
           //TODO Please include your logice her
       }
   }
   ```
8. **Unit testing**

   Please write tests so that these problems could be avoided easily.

Comment: Count vs Any see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/305092/which-method-performs-better-any-vs-count-0

It's it's an IEnumerable use Any if it's not, use Count.

Answer (score 1):

You should start with making this code more readable by

- reducing the horizontal spacing by introducing a guard clause like for instance

  ```
  if (rangeItemInfoFormulaToCompare.Count == 0) { return false; }
  ```

  could be placed at the top instead of `if (variable > 0) {do something } else {return false}`
- adding more usages of `var` where the type is obvious form the right side of the assignment.
- deleting commented out code, because such code is dead code and should be deleted.
- reducing the amount of comments. Comments are for telling **why** something is done. **What** is done should be told by the code itself by using meaningful names for variables, methods and classes.Btw, SHOUTING in comments isn't the way to go.

---

> ```
> if (IsSameRangesMeasurement(rangeItemsToCheck, rangeItemsToCompare))
> {
>     foreach (var tempToCheck in rangeItemInfoFormulaToCheck)
>     {
>         //FILTER FORMULAS TO COMPARE BY MEASUREMENT AND RANGE INFO. ID
>         var listFilterByMeasurementInfoId = rangeItemInfoFormulaToCompare
>             .Where(x => string.Compare(x.measurementName.Trim(), tempToCheck.measurementName.Trim(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
>             .ToList();
>
>         foreach (var tempToCompare in listFilterByMeasurementInfoId)
>         {
>             bool conditionA = false;
>             bool conditionB = false;
>
>             //IF BOTH ARE SAME MEASUREMENT
>             if (tempToCheck.measurementName.Trim().ToLower() == tempToCompare.measurementName.Trim().ToLower())
>             {
> ```

Here you are creating a `List<T>` by using linq with a condition on the `measurementName`'s being the same, which is done in a good way using `string.Compare` with a `StringComparision` enum but a few lines later you are again checking if both names are the same (although in a sub optimal way).
This second check should be skipped if you don't want to distinguish between culture relevant naming differences.

The call to `ToList()` on the resulting `IEnumerable<T>` of the mentioned linq query isn't needed at all, because you are only iterating over it.

Comment: I was told comments should be caps.

Comment: I cannot remember, maybe from my senior long time ago.